# qprinter not found in C++

Tags: c++, yum, qprinter, fedora20

This is a very basic question. I have searched the history of the of this forum and not found anything directly applicable to this app in C/C++.
I am building the code on Fedora20. I have the following libraries, installed using yum:

```
qt5-qtbase-devel qt5-qtdeclarative-devel qt5-qtscript-devel 
qt5-qtwebkit-devel qt5-qtsvg-devel qt5-qttools-devel

[root@localhost subsurface]# qmake-qt5 --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.4.0 in /usr/lib64
```

I use qmake like this:

```
make-qt5
```

No errors displayed, I assume make file ok and header files generated are ok.

Upon make, the following Qt-related errors:

```
[root@localhost subsurface]# make
```

(1)

```
compiling main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/QtGui/QTextEdit:1:0,
             from .uic/ui_mainwindow.h:26,
             from qt-ui/mainwindow.h:14,
             from main.cpp:11:
/usr/include/QtGui/qtextedit.h:235:16: error: ‘QPrinter’ has not been declared
 void print(QPrinter *printer) const;
            ^
```

(2)

```
In file included from qt-ui/tableview.h:10:0,
                 from .uic/ui_diveplanner.h:26,
                 from qt-ui/diveplanner.h:140,
                 from .uic/ui_mainwindow.h:30,
                 from qt-ui/mainwindow.h:14,
                 from main.cpp:11:
.uic/ui_tableview.h: In member function ‘void Ui_TableView::retranslateUi(QGroupBox*)’:
.uic/ui_tableview.h:49:87: error: ‘UnicodeUTF8’ is not a member of ‘QApplication’
         TableView->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("TableView", "GroupBox", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
```

I suspect I am missing one or two more Qt libraries. Which library files contain QPrinter and UnicodeUTF8?
Any advice, please?
Kind regards,
willem

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on PacketSender-2.0 project

```
# yum remove qt-devel
# yum install qt5-qtbase-devel  -y 

$ make clean
$ qmake-qt5
$ make
```